# Как в Spring отдавать json в ответ на «/login, /logout»?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Добрый день! 
Стоит задача реализации login/logout с использованием Spring. Большинство найденных примеров показывают реализацию с перенаправлением на форму логина(jsp, html). Мне же нужно формировать json ответ для frontend разработчика. Подскажите в чем принципиальные отличия этих двух подходов? (мб ткните носом в примеры или документацию которые мне не попались на глаза).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так просто верните POJO, которое описывает ваш JSON-ответ.

```
@Controller
public class AuthController {

    @RequestMapping(patrh="/login", method=POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public AuthDto doLogin(...) {
        // ... 
        return authDto;
    }

    @RequestMapping(patrh="/logout", method=POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public AuthDto doLogin() {
        // ...
        return authDto;
    }
}
```